# Typescript: Get the type of the last parameter of a function type

Tags: typescript

Assume I have a function type, e.g.

```
type somefntype = (a: number, b: string, c: boolean) => void
```

I need the type of that function types last parameter:

```
type lastparamtype = LastParameter<somefntype> // lastparamtype == boolean
```

How do I define `LastParameter`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Update:

To properly infer the last parameter type of optional parameters, this has to be extended somewhat.

```
type Last<T extends any[]> = T extends [...infer I, infer L] ? L : T extends [...infer I, (infer L)?] ? L | undefined : never

type LastParameter<F extends (...args: any) => any> = Last<Parameters<F>>;
type somefntype = (a: number, b: string, c?: boolean) => void;
type lastparamtype = LastParameter<somefntype>; // boolean | undefined
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgZ2AHgCpQgD2BAdgEwSjlxAG0BdAPigF4p0scCiyA6DgS1wDMIAnKAEkANFG59BMClAD8sKAC4GGbHkJR2XXgOFiAFBN0wAlLJnyYUAD5QArgQg9uEfEqi4IANwEAoUJCwiMAACnD8cAC2EDj8yABiqswa+hxs4QDmCMokICZ0NLk09PBIyGER0bEICVRUANz+4NAIAPbRPLgB0PT6cMq4dpEARgJiw8pI-NwZYgDGssrDra0ANhAk+bQ0Xq2c+I3dUKvBYOFRRyXBFVExAshtHV3NDVAA9G9Qy2sbuDb2jmcnnwviAA)

---

Update: TypeScript 4.0 introduced [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types), which means that `Last` can now be implemented simply as

```
type Last<T extends any[]> = T extends [...infer I, infer L] ? L : never;
```

And the rest works as normal:

```
type LastParameter<F extends (...args: any)=>any> = Last<Parameters<F>>;
type somefntype = (a: number, b: string, c: boolean) => void
type lastparamtype = LastParameter<somefntype> // boolean
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgZ2AHgCpQgD2BAdgEwSjlxAG0BdAPigF4p0scCiyA6DgS1wDMIAnKAEkANFG59BMClAD8sKAC4ouCADcBAbigAoUJFiJgABTj84AWwg5+yAGIZseQlAAUHNmYDmCZSRAAlHQ0-jT08EjIpuZWNgj2VFSaOnrg0AgA9lY8uPrQ9K5wyrgArhYARgJi5cpI-NxeYgDGyuUZGQA2ECRBtDRqGZz4yXlQHUZgZpaj4UbRltYCyJnZuWlJUAD0m1Btnd24OkA)

---

TypeScript 3.0 introduced [tuple types in rest and spread expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions), specifically to allow programmatic conversion between the types of function parameter lists and [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple).  There's a type alias called `Parameters<F>` [defined in the standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.4.5/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1471-L1474) that returns the parameter list of a function as a tuple.

It's annoying but possible to get the last element of a tuple type with a fixed but arbitrary length:

```
// Tail<T> returns a tuple with the first element removed
// so Tail<[1, 2, 3]> is [2, 3]
// (works by using rest tuples)
type Tail<T extends any[]> = 
  ((...t: T)=>void) extends ((h: any, ...r: infer R)=>void) ? R : never;

// Last<T> returns the last element of the tuple
// (works by finding the one property key in T which is not in Tail<T>)
type Last<T extends any[]> = T[Exclude<keyof T, keyof Tail<T>>];
```

Putting those together you get

```
type LastParameter<F extends (...args: any)=>any> = Last<Parameters<F>>;
```

And we can test it:

```
type somefntype = (a: number, b: string, c: boolean) => void
type lastparamtype = LastParameter<somefntype> // boolean
```

Looks good to me.  [Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgSwDYB4ZQgD2BAdgEwGco5cQBtAXQD4oBeKACkYDo3gAuWASntoDcA9gny8sOAsWYAoKFAAWXUiAA0sqGxYAnLglwAzCFqgAlabzoDho9QH5T6rrgj8jAbmmhIUADJxCwGgY2HhEJGRUtAww5ACimADGSACu+BAoANYQIIL6sCpQWTl58Mho1NSUHl7QfgEACnBacAC2EDhaKABiwRJhrGxNAOaESmQWtMpRvv6Bjc1tHYTdFR6e4NCEgm36uDX0THBOyS0ARkYFp1wBWnpDBQlcp4KCSBCkE1BCItUbUEizMBNVr7Bh1YDzVrtIwoLY7PYbahuKAAehRUGer3euGkQA)

Comment: Added in an edit for support for optional parameters as well, since I spent way too much time looking up this myself

Answer (score 3):

Here is yet a another solution which is a slight modification of jcalz answer to make it more generic using some recursive conditional types:

```js
type Head<T extends any[]> = T extends [any, ...any[]] ? T[0] : never;
type Tail<T extends any[]> =
    ((...t: T) => any) extends ((_: any, ...tail: infer U) => any)
        ? U
        : [];
type HasTail<T extends any[]> = T extends ([] | [any]) ? false : true;

type Last<T extends any[]> = {
    0: Last<Tail<T>>
    1: Head<T>
}[
    HasTail<T> extends true ? 0 : 1
];

type LastType = Last<Parameters<somefntype>>; // boolean
```

It might be interesting to consider replacing `any` with `unknown` as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, [recursive conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980) are [not supported](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980#issuecomment-421354117).  The official word is ["don't do it"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897#issuecomment-401418254), and ["we're not ready to support this sort of thing"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980#issuecomment-438722312).  For now I'd keep code like this in a sandbox for fun, but not let it anywhere near a production/shared environment.

Comment: I think that would be better to use `unknown` instead of `any`: `type Head<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [unknown, ...unknown[]] ? T[0] : never`

Answer (score 1):

As of TypeScript 4.0 with variadic tuple support, it's also possible to use the following to get the last type in a tuple type:

```
type LastType<T extends [unknown, ...Array<unknown>]> = T extends [...infer A, infer L] ? L : never;
```

Answer (score 0):

For function with 3 args solution wil be

```
type somefntype = (a: number, b: string, ddd: boolean) => void
type LastParameter<T> = T extends (a: infer A1, b: infer A2, c: infer A3) => any ? A3 : never;

type lastArg = LastParameter<somefntype>;  // === boolean
```

Name of function agruments does not metter.

For function with arbitrary number of arguments task become a bit complicated. We may use `...rest` but it will be array.

```
type LastParameter<T> = T extends (...rest: infer A3) => any ?
    A3 : never;
type lastArg = LastParameter<somefntype>; // lastArg === [number, string, boolean]
```

Get last element of resulting tuple is a bit challenging. One possible solution has been inspired from this [article](https://dev.to/miracleblue/how-2-typescript-get-the-last-item-type-from-a-tuple-of-types-3fh3).

```
type Prev<T extends number> = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62][T];
type GetLength<original extends any[]> = original extends { length: infer L } ? L : never;
type GetLast<original extends any[]> = original[Prev<GetLength<original>>]

type somefntype = (a: number, b: string, ddd: boolean) => void
type LastParameter1<T> = T extends (...rest: infer A3) => any ?
    A3 extends any[] ? GetLast<A3> : never
    : never;
type lastArg = LastParameter<somefntype>; // boolean for 3 arg function
```

Second solution has limitaion on number of arguments of the function.