# How can I omit a first parameter from the function parameters type?

Tags: typescript

I have a `sendMessage` from a third-party library function with parameters:

```
function sendMessage(chatId: number | string, text: string, extra?: tt.ExtraEditMessage)
```

I want to create another function that will send a message to a specific user. I want this function to have all parameters of the original function:

```
export async function sendMessageToAdmin(text: string, extra?: tt.ExtraEditMessage)
```

But I want for this type declaration to be DRY and update automatically when I update a third-party dependency, so I can use `Parameters` utility type:

```
type SendMessageParameters = Parameters<sendMessage>

export async function sendMessageToAdmin(...parameters: SendMessageParameters)
```

However, I also want to omit the first parameter, `chatId`, since I'll be setting it on my own. Unfortunately, `Omit` utility type only works for properties and not tuple members.

How can I construct a type that will have all parameters of a function instead of a first one, or one with specific name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need just to return Tail of tuples

```js
function sendMessage(foo: number, baz: string, bar: number[]) { }

type Tail<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail] ? Tail : never;

function otherFunc(...parameters:Tail<Parameters<typeof sendMessage>>){} // baz: string, bar: number[]
```

Comment: Here you can find how to achieve it in TS 3.* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56368755/typescript-get-the-type-of-the-last-parameter-of-a-function-type

Comment: Thanks! I like this more than my solution, as it leaves me with more composable utility types.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it by modifying the original `Parameters`:

```
type ParametersExceptFirst<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (
    ignored: infer _,
    ...args: infer P
) => any ? P : never
```